# Remove page number

Tags: abcpdf, abcpdf9

I am using AbcPdf to convert pdf files into html pages.
It works well but the conversion process adds page number in the header of the pages.
Can I remove them?

```
<div style="margin:1ex;">
    <div style="width:100%">
        <table style="border:0;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="eeeeee" align="right">
                        <font face="arial,sans-serif"> <b>Page 1</b> </font> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does AbcPdf let you create HTML pages? I don't see where their site mentions that. At any rate, what does the header HTML look like?

Comment: Yes, the save method of the WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc object allows to export a document as html.
This is the header added by the conversion process:

http://uptiki.altervista.org/viewer.php?file=5mrgfidpq6kbdldqryz3.png

Thanks.

Comment: I asked for HTML, not a screenshot. I'm wondering whether you can simply remove the element with CSS.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry.
But I wanted to know if there was a setting for ABCPDF in order to ensure that the header is not generated.
This is the header added to page:
    <div style="margin:1ex;">
      <div style="width:100%">
        <table style="border:0;width:100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="eeeeee" align="right">
                <font face="arial,sans-serif">
                  <b>Page 1</b>
                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in comments.

Comment: That's some really awful HTML. A table with one cell is just clutter and can be confusing for screen reader users. The font tag is deprecated. Inline CSS isn't ideal. You can probably target the page numbers with CSS or jQuery, but I'd seriously consider a different approach.